# SQL server Query for SUM group

Tags: sql-server, syntax, sum, grouping

I have table:

```
-------------------------------------
|  Code  |  Name  |   Type   |  Qty |
-------------------------------------
|  0001  |  Mouse | Purchase |  5   |
|  0002  | KeyBrd | Purchase |  8   |
|  0003  |  Mouse |   Sale   |  2   |
-------------------------------------
```

i want to select them like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
|  Code  |  Name  |   Total Purchase |  Total Sale | Stock |
------------------------------------------------------------
|  0001  |  Mouse |         5        |      2      |   3   |
|  0002  | KeyBrd |         8        |      0      |   8   |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Im so confused, please help me with the query, thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
SELECT
    Code,
    Name,
    TotalPurchase = SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Purchase' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END),
    TotalSale = SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Sale' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END),
    Stock = SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Purchase' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Sale' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END)
    FROM YourTable
       group by  Code,
                Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Conditional aggregation with the help of `case` expression is one approach

```
select min(Code) Code, 
       Name,
       sum(case when Type = 'Purchase' then Qty else 0 end) [Total Purchase],
       sum(case when Type = 'Sale' then Qty else 0 end) [Total Sale],
       sum(case when Type = 'Purchase' then -Qty else Qty end) Stock 
from table t
group by Name
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use like below.(**Using Pivot**) Please try this.

**Data Generation**

```
CREATE TABLE TableCase
(
   Code VARCHAR(10)
  ,[Name]  VARCHAR(10)
  ,[Type] VARCHAR(20)
  ,Qty INT
)
GO

INSERT INTO TableCase VALUES
('0001','Mouse'  ,'Purchase',5),
('0002','KeyBrd' ,'Purchase',8),
('0003','Mouse'  ,'Sale',2   )
GO
```

**SOLUTION**

```
SELECT MIN(Code) Code,[Name] 
  , ISNULL(SUM([Purchase]),0) [TotalPurchase]
  , ISNULL(SUM([Sale]),0) TotalSale
  , ISNULL(SUM([Purchase]),0) - ISNULL(SUM([Sale]),0) Stock
FROM TableCase
PIVOT 
(
    MAX(Qty) FOR [Type] IN ([Purchase],[Sale])
)t
GROUP By [Name]
ORDER BY [code]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Code       Name       TotalPurchase TotalSale   Stock
---------- ---------- ------------- ----------- -----------
0001       Mouse      5             2           3
0002       KeyBrd     8             0           8


(2 rows affected)
```